# Webpack: without dev-server, setting CORS headers for accessing API

Tags: javascript, webpack, cors, react-redux

I am using a `Webpack` for a `react-redux` app. I think the config currently does not use the hot-reload so its not on `localhost:<port>`, instead it compiles all the resources to a single index.js that runs the entire react-redux application so I am under the impression it is not using the webpack-dev-server and just static file that is created.

I want to be able to set the `CORS` headers so that I can make an API call.
I have tried a lot of things in the `webpack.config.js`, nothing has worked.

The error goes like this,
`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.`

Comment: CORS headers should be set on the server receiving the request, it's not something that you can set client-side.

Comment: I understand... So wouldn't this be something to be set in webpack? There is no server... Its just a static file, so the native file system is basically serving it..

Comment: Well, there's an API server somewhere I assume? That's where the headers should be set.

Comment: My main issue is what headers and how to put them in webpack.. cannot find it

Comment: There’s nowhere you can put headers in webpack that will solve the problem. Your code is trying to request data from some other third-party server, right? That server that your code is trying to send the request to is the server that needs to have the correct headers set.

Comment: Wait, does it not say the requested resource does not have the correct `headers`. Does it not mean I have to supply the header in webpack.

Answer (score 0):

*Eventually,* I ended up changing the `headers` on the resource I was requesting(server that served the response) and added 
`"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"` in it. The format may change depending on your server implementation but the header is basically supposed to have this.